# Advanced installer powershell script set property

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I am using advanced installer 10.7.1. I am adding the custom action of 'run windows powershell script'. What this script does is to check if the installer is being run on an azure vm or not. if it is, only then does it allow the user to install. The script runs fine on the vm, I've checked it. but now I need to display an error message on the basis of a script's result. which means I have to set some property in the script, on the basis of which I will display the error message.
can anybody tell me how to set advanced installer's property through a powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [limitation of Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not of Advanced Installer. PowerShell does not have access to the Session object of the installation, so you cannot set/get properties from a powershell script into an MSI, no matter the tool used to build the MSI.

The only custom actions that can be used to set a property (scheduled as **immediate** of course), are VBS scripts (inline or attached files) or DLLs written in [C++](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/serial-number-validation-dll.html) or [C#](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html). In C# is much easier as you have access to a lot of .NET API (but you also have the requirement of the .NET Framework to be on the end user machines).

**@ravikanth**

> It takes only script text and there is no associated action based on the return value. Weird!

This is how Windows Installer works, i.e. the technology against which all MSI packages are built. More specifically, custom actions running into an MSI cannot use the return code to communicate "*what ever they want*" with the main installation progress. Windows Installer accepts only a [strictly defined set of return codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), in the case of PowerShell custom actions in Advanced Installer, the return code is controlled in the background by the installer.

The scenario in which PS scripts are used in installations is that users usually need to them to make certain configurations on the machine, to prepare it for the installation. (like installing/activating Windows components, configuring network credentials, etc...) For very well and powerfully integrated custom code in the installers DLLs should be used as custom actions, as they provide a full cycle of communication (can get and set properties) and also can be debugged nicely into an IDE (by attaching to the installation process).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Advanced Installer works but you can always return a value from the script and then use that value in the caller. For example,

```
#Custom Script action
#Get the VM details
If (AzureVM) {
   $true
} else {
   $false
}
```

Once you have the result from the script, use that to switch the path of installation or display messages.

Comment: I don't think that is how advanced installer works. but thanks.

Comment: I suspected that and this is more of an advanced installer question. I installed quickly and checked how the custom action is created. It takes only script text and there is no associated action based on the return value. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

For Future Reference:

**Setting a property value from a script (for immediate custom actions)**

To set a property simply include a line with the following syntax in your script:

```
AI_SetMsiProperty YOUR_PROP <VALUE>
```

Where `YOUR_PROP` is the property and `<VALUE>` is the value assigned to it.

**NOTE: This only works with script that are set to run immediately.**